# How to access facts inside list

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to extract the elements of a list of pairs, but I'm only able to access the pairs. If I have a list like this:

```
list([p(a,b),p(c,d)]).
```

How can I access the elements `a, b, c, d`. For example, if I run:

```
list_s(X) :- list(L), member(X,L).

?- list_s(X).
X = p(a,b),
X = p(c,d)
```

I get all the pairs in the list. But I'm trying to write a rule:

```
listSelect(X) :- list(X), ( ... something).

?- listSelect(X).
X = a,
X = b,
X = c,
X = d
```

Is it possible to make a rule to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rubens' answer is perfectly fine, if, however, the order is important, you can also write:

```
list_select(X) :-
    list(L),
    member(p(A,B), L),
    (   X = A
    ;   X = B
    ).
```

As a small bonus, you only traverse the original list once.

If you wanted to make this work on functors with an arbitrary arity, you could instead write:

```
list_select(X) :-
    list(L),
    member(F, L),
    F =.. [_N|Args],
    member(X, Args).
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply run through the possible *facts* of your list, as in:

```
list([p(a, b), p(c, d)]).
listSelect(X) :- list(L), member(p(X, _), L).
listSelect(X) :- list(L), member(p(_, X), L).
```

Which gives:

```
?- listSelect(A).
A = a ;
A = c ;
A = b ;
A = d.
```